# AWS Cloud Formation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to use a simple JSON file (of my instance details) to configure a Cloud Formation template?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is unclear. Could you please Edit your question to provide more details? For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

That's basically what a CloudFormation template provides you. Since it is a template, you can also pass in parameters as variables.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Details on passing parameters from a config file:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/passing-parameters-to-cloudformation-stacks-with-the-aws-cli-and-powershell/

Comment: I am aware about parameters.But I use simple config file with CFT

Comment: I've edited my answer with more details. See the second link.

Comment: Hi thanks, I wanted to use parameters from config files in cloudformation template.I coudn't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have CFT parameters populated however you like. If you want to run / load the CFT from AWS console - add the parameters as either default or options within the CFT and choose them while creating the stack.

If you want to load them from a properties file - you can use any programming language of your choice to do so. A bash script that loads the properties or whatever, it's upto you and your use case. If you are using AWS cli to run the CFT use bash shell or power shell, if you are using AWS SDK to run your CFT - use the same language as your SDK etc.

Comment: I was able to make it by creating config files in json and passing the config file in aws code pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just aws cli, you can do something like this with a json parameters file:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stackname startmyinstance  
--template-body file:///some/local/path/templates/startmyinstance.json 
--parameters file:///some/local/path/params/startmyinstance-parameters.json
```